# NullPointerException at TextView.checkForRelayout() while setText()

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to implement ViewHolder pattern to improve perfomance while drawing on canvas over the map.
I need to create some labels for my markers. This method is called  while data processing in `draw()`

```
// now we create label view and convert it into bitmap
private Bitmap createLabelBitmap(GisLaborHistoryObject object, HistoryPoint point) {
    // create view from xml
    if (vh == null) {
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_gis_history_label, null, false);
        vh.tv = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.gislabeltext);
    }

    // set label content
    if (vh.tv != null) {
        if (!mSingleLaborHistory) {
            String name = "";
            name = object.getDisplayName();
            if (name == null || "".equals(name))
                name = object.getPersonId();
            if (name == null || "".equals(name))
                name = object.getLaborCode();
            if (name == null)
                name = "";

            vh.tv.setText(name);
        } else
            vh.tv.setText(point.getChangeDate());
    } 
    // measure resulting view
    vh.view.measure(spec, spec);
    vh.view.layout(0, 0, vh.view.getMeasuredWidth(), vh.view.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(vh.view.getWidth(), vh.view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvasToDraw.setBitmap(b);
    canvasToDraw.translate(-vh.view.getScrollX(), -vh.view.getScrollY());
    vh.view.draw(canvasToDraw);
    return b;
}
```

spec is

```
spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

the result is
Logcat:

```
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5497)
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2730)
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)
 04-29 17:12:34.057: E/AndroidRuntime(389):     at com.xxx.android.proj.ui.map.overlays.LaborsMarkerOverlay.createLabelBitmap(LaborsMarkerOverlay.java:164)
```

XML layout i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gislabeltext"
style="@style/labelStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp" />
```

what can be a reason of this error?

Comment: Note that this is an Android bug that appears to affect Android 4.4.3 and 4.4.4 devices, but is fixed in Android 5.1 - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75877.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After looking into android [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java?av=f) at line 5497 I noticed that there is a check using mLayoutParams. I looked whis case in the debug mode and it is really was null!
I add line which explicitly set this params. Now everything works fine.

```
vh.tv = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.gislabeltext);
vh.tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

My error was that I had have to set LayoutParams explicitly while inflating with ViewGroup root = null;
Everything had worked fine until I tried to reuse TextView multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `vh.tv.setText` method within your ui thread. So make sure you are doing it.

Comment: This sample works in Overlay's `draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)` method.