# Android: TextView Causes app to crash

Tags: android, textview, settext

I've got a TextView that crashes the app when trying to setText. I'm not using the XML layout and have set a custom view to handle everything. Obviously the app crashes when the screen is touched after the app is initalized.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(this);
    lv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mView = new MyView(this);
    TextView tvX = new TextView(this);
    lv.addView(tvX);
    lv.addView(mView);
    lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    tvX.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tvX.setText("Ahmad");
    setContentView(lv);
    mView.requestFocus();


public class MyView extends View {
    private TextView tvX;

    public void setTextView(TextView tv){
        tvX = tv;
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        tvX.setText("123"); 
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

```
08-27 00:39:49.859: E/MessageQueue-JNI(510):    at co.projx.touchpaint.TouchPaint$MyView.onTouchEvent(TouchPaint.java:286)
08-27 00:39:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at co.projx.touchpaint.TouchPaint$MyView.onTouchEvent(TouchPaint.java:286)
```

Comment: Post the logcat (stacktrace)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Posted logcat in Edit 1.

Comment: that is not the whole stack trace though and does not contain the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the same as here: [View becomes null on setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908406/view-becomes-null-on-settext/24910984#24910984)

You're missing the LayoutParams (WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT).

Comment: Where should I add that exactly in my code? I added it under LinearLayout lv and it's crashing still. I set it as `lv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: Considering you are making the layout programatically (who knows why), the linear layout is missing `FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT` and your textview is missing `WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT`, and I'm not sure what `myView` is.

Comment: It's a paint app, so the view was made programatically. I'm very new to Android. I would appreciate a code suggestion to fix my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to provide them layout parameters.