# Android Log NullPointerException

Tags: android, error-handling, nullpointerexception

When I work my code on 4.2.2 tablet, It works but When I work 4.4.4 tablet, It doesn't work.

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xxx, PID: 28367
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7116)
    at android.widget.TextView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TextView.java:9549)
    at android.view.View.resolveRtlPropertiesIfNeeded(View.java:12354)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16743)
    at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:665)
    at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:618)
    at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:461)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1271)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:591)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1055)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:591)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1235)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:327)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2439)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1175)
 at android.view.ViewR
```

I'm using viewpager on fragment. And I declaration Textview,Edittext.. in fragmentAktif().

Code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpage_esnafbilgileri, null);
    root.destroyDrawingCache();
    root.clearAnimation();
    fragmentAktif();
    return root;
}
```

I don't understand reason. I can't see reason of error.

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281357/nullpointerexception-at-textview-checkforrelayout-while-settext

Comment: fragmentAktif(); post this method code

Comment: @Raghavendra It don't worked me.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa I don't understand you

Comment: what you have written in this method? fragmentAktif();

Comment: `activityEsnaf=SingletonClass.getCurrentActivityEsnaf();
 esnafOzetObj=SingletonClass.getEsnafOzetObj();
 isyeri = SingletonClass.getIsyeri();
 serviceObj = new MobilServisAyarlar();

        spnOzetKonutMu = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spnOzetKonutMu);
        spnOzetIsyeriHekimiMi = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spnOzetIsyeriHekimiMi);
        spnOzetAktifMi = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spnOzetAktifMi);
        spnOzetBeyazZambak = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spnOzetBeyazZambak);`